# Bash: wait for process to exit while tailing log file

Tags: bash

In a bash script, I'm waiting on a child process's pid using wait. That child process is writing to a log file.  Is there a way in the bash script to tail that log file to std out while at the same time waiting on the process to complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `tail` command to follow the file while you wait for the command to finish.

```
command &
cmdpid=$!
tail -f -n +0 logfile &
wait $cmdpid
kill $!
```

This is in spirit similar to William's solution, but with one important difference: it will correctly print the log file if it takes longer for `command` to finish than it does for `cat` to print the file (quite likely, as `cat` is very fast). The `-n +0` option tells `tail` to print the whole file before it starts following updates.

Answer (score 1):

This makes it simpler:

```
command &
pid=$!
tail --pid=$pid -f /path/to/log
```

Answer (score 0):

Run cat in the background:

```
cmd-that-logs-to-file &
pid=$!
cat file &
wait $pid
kill $!  # Kill the cat
```

Comment: What if some other background process is started before `pid=$!` and after `cmd-that-logs-to-file &` ?

Comment: @KingsIndian  If you didn't record the pid, then you cannot reliably wait for a particular process.

Comment: `$!` gives the *most recent* background process' id which could potentially be something else.

Comment: @Kingsindian  I do not understand your point.  Yes, if you fail to record $! immediately after starting a background process, then you don't have that process' pid.  How is that relevant?

Comment: What I meant was if some other background process is started between the execution of the 1st & 2nd line of your script then $! will give the wrong pid.

Comment: @mark I meant cat.  You could certainly use `tail -f` instead, but cat seems more appropriate.

Comment: @kingsindian $! actually refers to the last process id **in the current shell**, not throughout the system, so there really is no race condition there. The documentation might seem a bit unclear. But otherwise, $! wouldn't be useful, because a race condition like the one you asked about could always happen