# Reading Files During Docker Build

Tags: docker

Is there a way to access the temporary filesystem in use during a docker build step?

My particular scenario involves a basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
...
RUN long_running_script.sh
...
```

where `long_running_script.sh` is a third party script that dumps any issues it encounters whilst running to a file `log.txt` and not to `stdout`.

Is there any way for me to view `log.txt` whilst that (multiple hour long) script is being run, i.e. whilst that build step is in progress?

Comment: Should this long running script really be running at build time?

Comment: can you just change script and log output to stdout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my version of docker (24.0.6 on Ubuntu 22.04) all new files in a container filesystem are located at `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/CONTAINERID/diff` .

In other versions, or if manually configured to use a different filesystem driver,  this will be in a different location (e.g. `/var/lib/docker/btrfs/`, see https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/ for all options)

The `CONTAINERID` of the in progress build layer is hidden (as this build layer does not appear as a container in `docker ps -a`). Nevertheless the `log.txt` can be found by either guessing the correct `CONTAINERID`, or if all other containers than the build are stopped it will be the newest container (identified with `ls -t /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ | head -1`)

Comment: If  someone were to discover how to reliably find the `CONTAINERID` of an in progress build layer, add that as another more complete answer and I'll accept that preferentially!

Answer (score 1):

you can add extra bash `wrapper.sh` script like

```
command &
cmdpid=$!
tail -f -n +0 logfile &
wait $long_running_script.sh
kill $!
```

(solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358911/6515755)

and run in your docker build

```
RUN wrapper.sh
```

Comment: This works with a little modification (adding parameters to make more flexible, add a touch of logfile incase not yet created, correctly obtain pid's) as below. Ideally I'd like to know if anyone knows an actual way to navigate the full FS of an in progress build layer as that would be a more flexible answer, so I'm going to hold off accepting this answer until I get more clarity on that...

`bash -c $1 & ;
cmdpid=$! ;
touch $2 ;
tail -f -n +0 $2 & ;
tailpid=$! ;
wait $cmdpid ;
kill $tailpid
`